# Getting infinite loop in fibonacci series in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, infinite-loop, fibonacci

```
#Program to print fibonacci until a range.
print "Fibonacci Series"
print "Enter a range"
range = raw_input()
first=1
second =1
print first
print ", "
print second
print ", "
third = 0
while(third < range):
    third=first+second
    print third
    print ", "
    first = second
    second = third
#End of program
```

Here, the program asks user for a range and prints the series upto the range. But, m getting the series of infinite loop. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range = raw_input()` sets `range` to be a **string**, e.g. it is assigning `range = '5'` rather than `range = 5`.

The comparison `third < range` will therefore always be `True` in Python 2.x *, as integers always compare less than strings:

```
>>> 10 < '5'
True
```

The minimal fix is to convert the input to an integer:

```
range = int(raw_input())
```

However, note that [`range` is a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), so you should pick a different name for that variable.

* *Note that in 3.x comparing a string with an integer causes an error:*

```
>>> 10 < '5'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    10 < '5'
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```